# Using COUNTIF, OFFSET, MATCH in Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I keep getting an error around this certain part of my COUNTIF function and cannot find out why. I believe it's cause the Offset function won't output a range. It seems to work fine if I manually put a range, but that isn't an option.

How do I get a range as an output using Match?

```
=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,MATCH(I$1,Sheet2!1:1,0)),"*Accountable*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to count "Accountable" from `$A$1` until the found match, so you are trying to "expand" the cell `A1` by as many cells. The parameter to enlarge the number of columns in the `OFFSET` function is parameter 5. Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,0,1,MATCH(I$1,Sheet2!1:1,0)),"Accountable")
'                              ^^^
```

You could use `INDEX` to achieve the same. (sometimes preferred for its non-volatility):

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet2!1:1,MATCH(I$1,Sheet2!1:1,0)),"Accountable")
```

Comment: This seems to work by itself, but when I add other criteria, it seems to break as #Value!
The current target Column is AF on Sheet2, so when I put that in, it works, so I'm not sure why this is breaking.



`=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$AL:$AL,"<>", OFFSET(Sheet2!A$1,0,0,1,MATCH(I$1,Sheet2!1:1,0)),"Accountable")`

Comment: @DavidRedford of course it will break because of this rule: `COUNTIFS` needs all its range parameters to be of exactly the **same size**. I think we're on a different issue now.

Comment: Ah. I did not know that as I'm a complete novice at this. Do you know if there is a way to make that work? Hypothetically if both ranges were 100 rows, would replacing it with just `$AL1:$AL50` and `$A1:$A50` work?

Comment: @DavidRedford problem is you have on one hand a column, and on the other hand a row. This is not  fit for `CountIfs`. I'm a bit lost now for what's your ultimate goal.

Comment: I used the Match to locate the column with a specific title (I1) in Sheet2. I could use "Sheet2!AF:AF" to get what I need, but the problem is this column keeps moving week to week so I'd like that criteria's range to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

A.S.H's tip on keeping the ranges the same solved most of it.
The second bit I was running into was just a miscalculation of columns.
It needed to be the match function and then minus 1 column.